# Running Parallels and VirtualBox for Docker in OS X?

Tags: virtualization, parallels-desktop, virtualbox, docker

I use Parallels for Windows while VirtualBox/Kinematic (Beta) for Docker in OS X -- but haven't yet tested at the same time because of possible problems such as [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=56508), dated to 2013 so many problems may be fixed. So what is the status of VM/Docker and Parallels and is it possible to run them at the same time and if yes, how in OS X? Precautions?

Comment: Please add the system and Parallels version

Comment: Parallels claims it works: http://kb.parallels.com/en/123356